# memcpy() leading to EXC_BAD_ACCESS in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, memcpy

I am getting `NSData` on my socket receiving function and I'm trying to copy that data in a `tempbuffer` of my audio class, I am using external type global variable to do so.

This is my code:

```
memcpy([recorder tempBuffer].mdata,(__bridger const void *)data,data.length);
```

Here recorder is my `extern` type global variable of audio class.

When control reaches this line of code an exception is thrown, what possibly be the mistake.

Comment: Why are you copying it at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are really three possibilities here:

1. `[recorder tempBuffer].mdata` is not a valid pointer. (What type is it, for instance? If it's a **NSMutableData**, you should be accessing its `mutableBytes` property.)
2. `[recorder tempBuffer].mdata` is not a valid pointer of sufficient size (`data.length`).
3. `(__bridger const void *)data` is not a valid pointer of sufficient size.

Of the three, I can guarantee that #3 needs addressing. A **NSData** is not itself the data you want, but an object wrapping the data you want. Instead of using a bridge here, you should be using `data.bytes`.

The other two, I can't help you with. I don't know what type `mdata` is or where it was allocated.

Comment: That won't cause a crash; more likely the destination is `NULL`.

Comment: It can if a block edge is violated by a sufficiently large length. But yes, checking the destination for null is also a good idea. **However**: The change I recommended is definitely needed here.

Comment: Sure; however it's not definitely the reason.

Comment: Update: I have verified that an EXC_BAD_ACCESS will be returned in the case I describe.

Comment: I didn't say "definitely not", I said "not definitely", however you have resolved the other possible reasons in your edit.

Comment: Thanks. Though you also said "That won't cause a crash," so I'm glad I tested this. :)

Comment: i have tried all the expected senerios but i could find any end, @steven Fisher

Comment: don't you think that my global extern would be the point due to which i am getting this exception

Comment: Nope. If you're getting this error, one of these three is true. (Well, additionally, your source buffer might be too small.)

Answer (score 0):

If the destination buffer is really a buffer you allocated with `malloc` or a `uint8_t` (or equivalent) buffer, you should:

1. Check to make sure that the destination buffer is big enough to hold the entire `data` contents.
2. Don't try to cast the `NSData` to a `(void *)` pointer, but rather use:

   ```
   memcpy(destination, data.bytes, data.length);
   ```

   If the `NSData` is not in a contiguous block (which in iOS 7 and later, it might not be), `data.bytes` will copy it to a contiguous buffer, which you can then use with `memcpy`.
3. Or better, you can avoid this redundant copy, by removing `memcpy` altogether:

   ```
   [data getBytes:destination length:data.length];
   ```

   This will, if the `NSData` is not in a contiguous block, avoid having `data.bytes` copy it to a contiguous buffer which you would then copy again with the `memcpy`.

   Bottom line, `NSData` has a rich interface that should eliminate the need to use low-level `memcpy` calls yourself.

From the question, it's not clear what `[recorder tempBuffer].mdata` is and how you allocated it, so perhaps you can clarify. Hopefully that's not another `NSData` object that you're trying to copy into.

Comment: i would look into the 3rd option but my tempbuffer is a struct not a NSData

Comment: The third option doesn't require that the destination, your `tempBuffer`, is a `NSData` (in fact, it's better if it's not). The `getBytes` is used to copy bytes _from_ a `NSData` into some arbitrary buffer.